# React Native : Why my Context.Consumer does not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's my createContext variable

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
const ModalContext = createContext({ valueModal : false, toggleContext : () => {} })
```

Here's my ModalContext Provider

```
<ModalContext.Provider value={ { valueModal : false, toggleContext : () => {} } }>

        <Tab.Navigator backBehavior="history" activeBackgroundColor="red">
          <Tab.Screen name="Mon compte" component={AccountScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Mes transferts" component={TransfertsScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Créer" component={CreerScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Suivi" component={SuiviScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="More" component={MoreScreen} listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                  tabPress: e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      console.log(previousRoute)
                      navigation.navigate(previousRoute[index-1]);
                      //dispatch({ type : 'visible' })
                      <ModalContext.Consumer>
                        {
                        ({ valueModal, toggleContext }) =>
                        {
                            toggleContext( !valueModal );
                        }
                    }
                      </ModalContext.Consumer>
                      console.log('reset state')
                  },
              })} />
        </Tab.Navigator>

        <ModalMenu/>

      </ModalContext.Provider>
```

Here's my consumer

```
<ModalContext.Consumer>
                {
                    ({ valueModal, toggleContext }) =>
                    {
                        <Modal isVisible={{valueModal}}>
                            <View style={{ ...styles.modal }}>

                                <Text style={{ color :'#f194ff', fontSize : 30, fontWeight : 'bold' }}>
                                    Un bon gros titre
                                </Text>
                            
                                <View style={{ padding : 10, width : '100%' }}>
                                    <MyButton title='Tutoriel' />
                                    <MyButton title='Nous contacter' />
                                    <MyButton title='FAQ' />
                                    <MyButton title='Réclamations' />
                                    <MyButton title='CGU' />
                                    <MyButton title='Infos' />
                                </View>
                                
                            </View>

                            <Button onPress={ () => toggleContext( !valueModal ) } title='goback' />
                        </Modal>
                    }
                }
            </ModalContext.Consumer>
```

Why, when I click on "More" tab, the modal does not shows ?

Even If I set the isVisible variable to true to the modal inside the consummer, thje modal does not show up. But Why ?

The plugin I use it https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal

Comment: Your toggleContext is an empty function, is should change a state to toggle visibility

Comment: Even if I force the <Modal isVisible= to true, no modal shows up

Comment: the prop is  visible not isVisible try that :)

Comment: It does not work but it's isVisible with the plugin I use

Comment: better check the plugin documentation then, the easiest way is to use a state and toggle values and check the behavior before checking using a context

Comment: You should update the question with the plugin then, its easy to check